# Efficient creation of numpy N array with step

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi i need to get faster solution of creating N dimensions numpy array in certain range. Original vectors_number will by over 10**6

My working code:

```
vectors_number = 12

data = []
for i in range(0, vectors_number, 4):
    data.append(np.arange(0+i, 4+i,1))

out = np.asarray(data)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
```

Comment: Where did you get the 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many numpy examples start with creating an array of this kind. I encourage you to browse the documentation a bit!

It is done efficiently by taking the whole range in 1D and then reshaping it:

```
np.arange(vectors_number).reshape((-1, 4))
```

Comment: Also note that `reshape` has no cost!